# Relations between 3 tables

Tags: cakephp

I have problem with relations between 3 tables.

mysql

- `Articles(id, title, text, author, category)`
- `Category(id, name)`
- `User(id, login, password)`

I try to create `CategoryController` function `view()`

model i have relation hasMany

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Articles' => array(
            'className' => 'Article',
            'foreignKey' => 'category'
     )
);
```

I get array with category name and articles is not working but I want to display author name under the article title.

i fixed database and used cake bake to generate everything but i still have the same problem

```
var_dump($category['News'])



   array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) "aa"
    ["short_text"]=>
    string(37) "bb"
    ["text"]=>
    string(36) "cc"
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-03 01:22:00"
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["category_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

i need get user name on category view on news its fine

Comment: I am agree with @schnauss. If you don't know how to write cake code  first configure your tables and relatoins then bake the model.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't following standard [CakePHP conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html) for table names or key names, which will cause you no end of trouble if you try to [use `bake` to generate your models.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html)

You should set your tables up like this:

-Articles: `id, title, text, user_id, category_id`

-Categories: `id, name`

-Users: `id, login, password`

Once you set up your tables and keys properly, `cake bake` will automatically discover how your models fit together, and bake you default views that will display author names next to article titles.